# Setup STUNNEL as client for both sides

Tags: stunnel

Good morning,

I need to configure a STUNNEL server to encrypt the traffic between a service that doesn't originally accept TLS and a service that properly accepts TLS PSK (Pre-Shared Key) (and this is important! The destination service only accepts TLS PSK).

Everything goes fine until the following situation arises. We have one server with a TCP port (without TLS PSK) open and listening for us to establish a connection with it. On the other hand, we have another server with a TCP port (with TLS PSK!) open and listening for us to establish a connection with it.

The problem is that neither of these servers can connect to STUNNEL to create the tunnel as we would normally do through the software.

Is there a method in STUNNEL for it to act as a client for both endpoints? I mean, can STUNNEL be the one to attempt to connect to BOTH endpoints?

[Connection diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72yaN.png)

Im expecting the STUNNEL connects to the non-tls server as client, and connect to the TLS endpoint as client too, no server ports on this stunnel configuration, and just use PSK cipher on the TLS endpoints, but no on the other side,

Comment: stunnel alone can't do that, but adding socat (plain-TCP client to plain-TCP client) should work. (Not tested, and this is not a programming or development problem and hence offtopic.)